# How to handle multiple user non consumable IAP in single Apple account in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have implement **non consumable IAP** for Upgrade Account functionality get life time access of feature in my application.

I am testing IAP on Sandbox Environment and i application after IAP  `original_transaction_id` store on server for restore validation check.

IAP with abc@gmail.com is working fine but after logout and login with difference account than i want to IAP than show pop up like this.

[image]

In Application this popup show when user want to Upgrade account but in Apple account already one user has purchase non consumable IAP.

i found possible solution  in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45630877/ios-non-consumable-iap-with-custom-user-accounts-management-multiple-purchases) over stack overflow.

So there is any possible solution or if i switch **non consumable IAP** to consumable IAP than Apple can accept the **consumable IAP** for one time purchase ?

Comment: the purchase is linked to the Apple ID, not your account. It does not sound like this is the right scenario for a non-consumable IAP. An appropriate response would be to track the original transaction id and if a user restores their purchase under a different login, remove the purchase benefits from their previous login.